# how to display chart using a list as a series of an chart elemnt

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have stored a list as a key value pair so that I can use key as `xValue` and Value as `yValues`. Now my question: How do I use this list for `AddSeries` element in `System.Web.Helpers` chart in `MVC`?

```
 double TotalDebts = 300000;

List<KeyValuePair<int, decimal>> dResult = new List<KeyValuePair<int, decimal>>();
List<int> lIndex = dResult.Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
List<decimal> lDepts = dResult.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++)
{

    if (TotalDebts > 0)
    {

        decimal DebtsLessIncome = Convert.ToDecimal(TotalDebts - 5000);
        decimal InterestCharged = Convert.ToDecimal((DebtsLessIncome * 5) / 100);
        decimal InterestDebt = Convert.ToDecimal(DebtsLessIncome + InterestCharged);
        decimal InterestDebtMLE = Convert.ToDecimal(InterestDebt + 1000);
        TotalDebts = Convert.ToDouble(InterestDebtMLE);

       dResult.Add(new KeyValuePair<int,decimal>());


    }
}
```

and I want to use this list in

```
var key = new Chart(width: 1000, height: 400, theme: Green)
          .AddTitle("Employee Chart")
          .SetXAxis("Total Year", 1)
          .SetYAxis("Money")
          .AddLegend("")

           .AddSeries(
           chartType: "line",
           name: "Current Scenario",
           xValue:lIndex,
           //new[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" },
           yValues:lDepts)
           //new[] { "220000", "200000", "180000", "150000", "120000", "50000", "35000", "25000", "15000", "10000", "0" })
```

I just tried with a hard coded value. It works fine, but I don't know how I can assemble that list to the `xValue` and `yValues`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used charting in MVC before, however reading the code sample you provided it will work if you change the following:

```
List<int> lIndex = dResult.Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
List<decimal> lDepts = dResult.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

to be `string` arrays:

```
string[] lIndex = dResult.Select(x => x.Key.ToString()).ToArray();
string[] lDepts = dResult.Select(x => x.Value.ToString()).ToArray();
```

...

For charting, I prefer to return JSON result from the server-side and render it using one of the many excellent JavaScript charting libraries.

Comment: nope this does not work  i will give you a hint if u can suggest me when i hover mouse to xValue it shows me  (parameter)System.Collection.IEnumerablexValue